# Grails after changing type from simple string to text - Data too long for column 'text' at row 1

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

In grails 2.3.4 on domain level I add new piece of code :

```
static mapping = {
    text type: "text"
}
```

Before I had just simple variablle with name text. I Change in my sql type to text (TEXT - 65,535 bytes). But when I'm trying to save 50 000 chars I get:

```
Data truncation: Data too long for column 'text' at row 1. Stacktrace follows:

com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'text' at row 1
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4118)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
        at nl.mycubes.questionnaire.engine.QuestionnaireService$_saveLabels_closure21.doCall(QuestionnaireService.groovy:577)
        at nl.mycubes.questionnaire.engine.QuestionnaireService.saveLabels(QuestionnaireService.groovy:560)
        at nl.mycubes.questionnaire.engine.QuestionnaireService.saveQuestion(QuestionnaireService.groovy:502)
        at nl.mycubes.questionnaire.engine.TreeController.saveQuestion(TreeController.groovy:316)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: did you look into mysql to make sure new datatype was applied ? did you run grails db migration plugin or alter the table yourself

Comment: I alter table (change type to text) and check after type is TEXT.

Comment: change type to longtext and then try.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop and create new database. It should works fine as expected..